# When making the method static -- an object reference is required to access non-static field,

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

an object reference is required to access non-static field, method or property

When I make the GetCartId  static Visual Studio complains

```
public class Uno
{
    private readonly HttpContext context;

    public Uno()
    {
    }

    public Uno(HttpContext _context)
    {
        context = _context;
    }
    public static string GetCartId()
    {
        string cartId = "";
        var stringId = context.Session.GetString("cart");
        if(stringId == null)
        {
            cartId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            stringId = cartId;
        }
        else if(stringId != null)
        {
            cartId = stringId;
        }
        return cartId;
    }
}
```

Comment: @poke, I was wrong to vote-close this one with general "access instance member from static" question. This question is rather `HttpContext.Current` related.

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing `context` from that method. It needs to be static in order to be able to use it:

```
private static readonly HttpContext context;
```

`readonly` doesn't make it `static`. It is `readonly` on instance level. (`const` on the other hand is static by definition)

**I would warn you though to use `static` with a `HttpContext` since `static` is shared across instances in  ASP.NET. You might end up mixing user sessions!**

Use `HttpContext.Current` from the static method itself.

Answer (score 2):

`context` is not static so you cant access it from a static method without an instance of `Uno`. But even then you can't access it because it's `private`.

Instead I would use [`HttpContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.100).aspx) which works even in a static method:

```
public static string GetCartId()
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    if(context == null) return null;
    string cartId = "";
    var stringId = context.Session.GetString("cart");
    if(stringId == null)
    {
        cartId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        stringId = cartId;
    }
    else if(stringId != null)
    {
        cartId = stringId;
    }
    return cartId;
}
```

Comment: yes, I have realized and edited my code. Now, it works thank you.